# Ionic window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL not working for jpgs

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I'm using the gallery to access images to upload. I'm having no trouble when I am uploading the image uri directly, but when I need to use fileEntry (for multi-part uploads) jpgs are not returning a fileEntry from their uri.  *Note: i'm using async:await, but I have the same issue with standard promises*

For example the following is the code I'm using to get the image uri

```
var imageUri = await this.takePicture(Object.assign(this.defaultOptions,{sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM}));
let newFile = new File([imageUri], "filename");
this.uploadFile(newFile);
```

The following is the code for `takePicture()` that returns the imageUri

```
try{
  return await this.camera.getPicture(options);
}catch(err){
  ...handle error
}
```

This code above **successfully** uploads both `png` and `jpg` files.

This code below fails to retrieve a fileEntry for only `jpg` files.

```
    /**
   * Returns a file entry for the image uri provided
   * @param imgUri image Uri to get file entry for
   */
  private async getFileFromImageUri(imgUri){ 
    try{
      var fileEntry = await this.resolveFileAsPromise(imgUri);
    }catch(err){
      // fileEntry = await this.createNewFileEntry(imgUri);
      this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');  //TODO: images that are .jpg seem to have trouble being resolved to a file.
    }
    return fileEntry;      
  }
```

`resolveFileAsPromise(ImgUri);` is a promise wrapper for `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imgUri, resolve, reject);` It returns the following error

`FileError {code: 5}` for jpgs only.  The error code means that there was some trouble with the format of the jpg? This doesn't make sense to me as all of that is being handled internally. The images are not corrupted or anything so it leads me to believe that possibly the error code is misleading? [error code docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings)

Has anyone encountered this issue? I am testing on a live android device (not an emulator).

I feel that the above demonstrates that the image uri is not the problem since it works to upload images when I don't need to get to the fileEntry.  But, when I do, it works for only a particular filetype `png`s.

Comment: I'm having the same issue only on Android device. I think `JPEG` is not the one causing the problem.

Comment: What do you think the problem is? @JeffMinsungKim

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim I found a solution. The problem was the path being returned by jpgs camera.getPicture was not a full path (pngs return the full path: includes `file://`)

Comment: You mean it does not return a full path on Android device? That's weird. It used to be worked fine on both devices. Anyway, I'll try your answer. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the issue

```
var imageUri = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
#FIX
if(this.platform.is('android') && !imageUri.includes("file://")) {
    imageUri = `file://${imageUri}`;
}
var fileEntry = await this.resolveFileAsPromise(imgUri);
```

The problem seems to be that for some reason on android the camera library does not return jpgs with the full `file://` path as needed for the cordova File plugin.

If all that is needed to be done is prepend `file://` it makes me wonder why that's not already happening for jpgs.  Especially since it is working/returning file paths correctly for pngs.

Also, cordova returning an error code of 5 is deceiving as it seems to indicate that there is a problem with the file being referenced, not with the path.